# Anychart Polar Plot line performance

Tags: javascript, java, android, anychart, anychart-8.2

I was trying to draw a polar plot using the Anychart library and I found a strange behavior that I wanted to share. I wanted to draw a polar plot with a number of points that are linked with a line representing different angles. The strange behavior I saw is that sometimes the line belongs to the "shortest path" between points and sometimes belongs to the "longest path", connecting the dots always in a "clockwise" direction.
In my brain, the line should go "clockwise" when increasing the angle (for instance, moving from 45º to 135º) and "counterclockwise" when decreasing the angle (for instance, moving from 135º to 45º).

My question is, is there an option to decide the direction of the line connecting the dots? I have done a test here with the "Anychart" playground option to show this scenario (https://playground.anychart.com/F6srRlRo/12). The "always-clockwise" performance can be seen in the upper left plot, while the desired performance, achieved by dividing the lines into 3 different line series, can be seen in the upper right plot. The problem of the solution I found is that, for longer datasets, depending on the data it might be required to use thousands of different series, which lowers considerably the rendering time of the plot (this can be seen in the lower left and lower right plots, where the left one is faster, but is "always-clockwise" and the right one is slower, but as desired).

any help in how to improve rendering time or plot everything in one simple Line data series?

Comment: The current version of the library v8.9.0 always provides clock-wise direction for the line rendering in the Polar chart. Unfortunately, there's no possibility to override this behavior.

Comment: Will you consider modifying this behavior in the next version? Because I think it is not much intuitive the Anychart performance in this case...

Comment: We will take it into account for future updates.